# Can't get handleClick to fire

Tags: javascript, aura, trailhead

Working through a [simple Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics/lex_dev_lc_basics_controllers?trailmix_creator_id=strailhead&trailmix_slug=prepare-for-your-salesforce-platform-developer-i-credential) that illustrates handling of button click.  The component that contains the button looks like this:

[image: aura component as viewed in Developer Console]

[image: Controller as viewed in Developer Console]

When I run this from a harness, I don't get a single message in the console log, which makes me think it isn't firing.

When I ask Trailhead to check my work, I get this message:

"Challenge not yet complete in Diseased Camel Playground
The campingListItem component doesn't contain a button with the correct label, or it doesn't call the correct function when clicked.

Comment: Just in case, did you saved the controller file of your component, as the image is not showing that?

Comment: seeing your screenshots, initial  thought is  your javascript controller is not saved.   you can see a start sign on your javascript controller.please save the component   nd let us know   if issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should save `campaingListItemsController.js`. :)

[image]